# Accessing a 16-bit pointer with ctypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pointers, ctypes

Why does the following not work?

```
import ctypes

class Test(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("my_pointer", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int16))]

t = Test()
t.my_pointer = ctypes.addressof(ctypes.c_int16(123))
```

Error:
`TypeError: expected LP_c_short instance, got int`
Is there way to generate a LP_c_short? Or any 16-bit pointer?

**EDIT**

Using byref instead of addressof causes:
`TypeError: expected LP_c_short instance, got CArgObject`

The Test structure is defined that way because it look's like that in a C-DLL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `byref` or `pointer` not `addressof`

```
a = ctypes.c_int16(123)
t.my_pointer(ctypes.byref(a)
```

Despite having a name like the C `&` operator addressof returns a int and not a ctypes pointer.

> ctypes.addressof(obj)
>
> Returns the address of the memory buffer as integer. obj must be an instance of a ctypes type

EDIT

Is this not working ? :

```
import ctypes

class Test(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("my_pointer", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int16))]

t = Test()

cc = ctypes.c_int16(123)
t.my_pointer = ctypes.pointer(cc)

print t.my_pointer[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert with `ctypes`, but following the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#pointers) the following works for me:

```
import ctypes

PI16 = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int16)

class Test(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("my_pointer", PI16),
    ]

t = Test()
t.my_pointer = PI16(ctypes.c_int16(123))
print(t.my_pointer[0])
```

otherwise, you could do:

```
t.my_pointer = ctypes.pointer(ctypes.c_int32(123))
```

the former will allow you to do strange things like:

```
PI(ctypes.c_int64(123))[0]
```

I.e. coerce between different width integer types, or worse…